# Change Instrument message not working with MIDI

Tags: java, midi

The below program produces a sound when I run it but when i want to change the instrument to something other than default the program stops producing sound at all though it compiles well. Not able to identify the fault.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
    public class MiniMiniMusicApp {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            if(args.length<2) {
                System.out.println("Please enter both instument and notes");
            }
            else {
                int instrument = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int notes = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                play(instrument, notes);
            }


        }// close main 

        static public void play(int instrument, int note) {

            try {   
                Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
                player.open();

                Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
                Track track = seq.createTrack();

     // the below Program_change code is creating the problem if we remove the below block the program creates sound

                ShortMessage first = new ShortMessage();
                first.setMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE,1,instrument,0);
                MidiEvent changeInstrument = new MidiEvent(first,1);
                track.add(changeInstrument);


                ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
                a.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON,1,note,100);
                MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a,1);  
                track.add(noteOn);



                ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
                b.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF,1,note,100);
                MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b,16);
                track.add(noteOff);

                player.setSequence(seq);
                player.start();



            } catch (Exception ex) {        
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this also happen for instrument 0? Try tick `0`.

Comment: when i changed `ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE` to `ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE` the program works, dont know why!

Comment: @CL. it works now for all the instrument, note combination except `102, 30` with which i was testing before i just now found it works even though i dont make the change from `PROGRAM_CHANGE` to `CONTROL_CHANGE` I am really surprised prior to asking the question i tried multiple combination but it didn't work earlier